# How many PCs does Crucible of the Gods need?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, fourthcore

The standard for D&D 4e is 5 PCs in a party, but *Crucible of the Gods* includes 6 pregenerated characters. Is this just to allow some choice and variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been talking with Sersa Victory himself (the author of the adventure) and apparently I missed the very first line on page 1: the game is intended for 4-6 players. Of course there are 6 character sheets.

I'm still investigating about why a game so hard can be a satisfying experience for both a 4-people party and for a party with 50% more HP, a better pool of trained skills which might result in less feats spent to improve them and in more attacks-per-round. I will post my discoverings here.

---

(Before replying myself, I linked SV here, knowing he has an account. Would he decide to reply, I'd happily mark his answer as accepted).